# OSX 10.11.4 on MBP Kernel Panic, whats wrong? (logs provided)

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

My MBP Has crashed 2 times the past week. After the first time, I updated everything and rebooted. What happens is it suddenly freezes and then shows a B/W screen saying that my computer restarted because of a problem.

Here are the logs for the two occasions:

**OCCASION 1**

```
    Anonymous UUID:       #REMOVED

Tue Mar 22 20:02:38 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff800aff076b): "soclose: NOFDREF"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.30.4/bsd/kern/uipc_socket.c:1263
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff801747b970 : 0xffffff800aadf792 
0xffffff801747b9f0 : 0xffffff800aff076b 
0xffffff801747ba40 : 0xffffff800b017664 
0xffffff801747ba60 : 0xffffff7f8d5b336c 
0xffffff801747bb50 : 0xffffff7f8d5afeed 
0xffffff801747bc80 : 0xffffff800af9600b 
0xffffff801747bcc0 : 0xffffff800aff27bc 
0xffffff801747be30 : 0xffffff800afcfcb6 
0xffffff801747be60 : 0xffffff800afc9787 
0xffffff801747bf00 : 0xffffff800afc95be 
0xffffff801747bf60 : 0xffffff800b02a731 
0xffffff801747bfb0 : 0xffffff800abf0a36 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall(163.0)[113F310F-1904-3F41-A206-1D275BF7A397]@0xffffff7f8d5ae000->0xffffff7f8d5b5fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: socketfilterfw

Mac OS version:
15D21

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C
Kernel slide:     0x000000000a800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800aa00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800a900000
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 21500922962843
last loaded kext at 20725437924976: at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4234 (addr 0xffffff7f8d62c000, size 303104)
last unloaded kext at 20819504327359: at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch 4234 (addr 0xffffff7f8d62c000, size 294912)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.22
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.41.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1020.17.1a1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

**OCCASION 2**

```
Anonymous UUID:       #REMOVED

Thu Mar 24 19:04:26 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80181ce40a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9a64aa95, type 0=divide error, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00000001116e7000, CR3: 0x00000001e769003a, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0x00010fe960000000, RBX: 0xffffff80e9b5b000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff8122d138e0, RBP: 0xffffff8122d138e0, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x000000000016a8c8
R8:  0x28f5c28f5c28f5c3, R9:  0xffffff80e9b463d8, R10: 0x0000000000000018, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff80e9b45000, R13: 0xffffff80e9b463d8, R14: 0xffffff802b867180, R15: 0xffffff80e9b5b000
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff7f9a64aa95, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00000001116e7000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 0

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8122d13570 : 0xffffff80180dab12 
0xffffff8122d135f0 : 0xffffff80181ce40a 
0xffffff8122d137d0 : 0xffffff80181ec273 
0xffffff8122d137f0 : 0xffffff7f9a64aa95 
0xffffff8122d138e0 : 0xffffff7f9a649439 
0xffffff8122d13b60 : 0xffffff7f9a63af11 
0xffffff8122d13bb0 : 0xffffff7f99458ba1 
0xffffff8122d13be0 : 0xffffff80186df277 
0xffffff8122d13d20 : 0xffffff8018197cc0 
0xffffff8122d13e30 : 0xffffff80180df283 
0xffffff8122d13e60 : 0xffffff80180c28b8 
0xffffff8122d13ea0 : 0xffffff80180d2665 
0xffffff8122d13f10 : 0xffffff80181b8bda 
0xffffff8122d13fb0 : 0xffffff80181eca96 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f99444000->0xffffff7f9947efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4FE41F9B-2849-322A-BBF8-A94816C003D6]@0xffffff7f9892c000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul(10.1.4)[778CF31F-9F30-3080-87C4-BDA457911639]@0xffffff7f9a62e000->0xffffff7f9a679fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4FE41F9B-2849-322A-BBF8-A94816C003D6]@0xffffff7f9892c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D]@0xffffff7f9905a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.3)[1B6944F0-F0F4-3D26-892C-46EB6C5C7433]@0xffffff7f9a513000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(31)[C89107EE-2DF2-3BC3-9F6D-3133D43ED7EF]@0xffffff7f99397000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.12.6)[F211EB28-182A-34BB-A610-87667618F925]@0xffffff7f9a627000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f99444000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
15E65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4E7B4496-0B81-34E9-97AF-F316103B0839
Kernel slide:     0x0000000017e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8017f00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 59766264380193
last loaded kext at 57839324506418: at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4234 (addr 0xffffff7f9aba7000, size 303104)
last unloaded kext at 57954461633607: at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch 4234 (addr 0xffffff7f9aba7000, size 294912)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   90.3
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.21.18
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.7
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.1.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.46.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  181
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.10.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.7
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   2.0.60
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.3
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Does anyone have an idea on whats going on?

Comment: How up to date is Little Snitch? Current is 3.6.3

Comment: Yes I think that littlesnitch may be causing issues.  What if you remove it?

Comment: Thanks guys, I uninstalled Little Snitch, that I actually removed a while back. Lets see if this works, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I've got exactly same crashes. Usually after waking up computer. I tried reseting NVRAM, SMC but did not help. I think that the only way to fix it is, going back with TimeMachine to previous release.

Comment: I will keep that in mind if my solution with little snitch doesn't work!